# Prove that $k^k\leq 2^k$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $k$ cardinal number, which $k>1$ and $k\cdot k=k$.How can i prove that $k^k\leq 2^k$? I tried to prove it in this way : $$ k^k \leq 2^{k^k}=2^{k\cdots k}$$ but its not so obvious why $2^{k\cdots k}=2^{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2^k=2^{k\cdot k}=(2^k)^k\ge k^k$$
since $2^k\ge k$.

Comment: Thank you very much finally it was much simpler than i was thinking.

Comment: Since $k > 1$ one might even say $2^k > k$